# Update form in parent site list when a task is completed in a subsite

Tags: 2013, tasks, sub-site, form-library

My company opens a project site whenever we start a new project in order to track progress. We use a task list to record when stages are completed/how long it took/etc.

With increasing projects coming in the manual transfer of data from the projects sites has become difficult.

The sites are all under the `"/ProjectManagement/"` site and are similar to `"/ProjectManagement/CompanyA/Project1"` where CompanyA can have multiple projects and there are multiple companies.

In the `"/ProjectManagement/"` site there are projects form library that contains all projects regardless of company. The items in the list need to be updated when their tasks are completed.

Is there any way to link the project sites task list to the item in the project form library?

This [article](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2012/10/using-content-search-web-part-and.html) seemed close but didn't solve my issue

Comment: Dear Robert , Please set your SharePoint version at tags